# MPDF Too Slow with a lot of Images

Tags: php, image, performance, pdf, mpdf

I am creating a pdf with a 1000 flyers, each flyer has 2 images and 25 flyers per page. To generate the PDF I am using MPDF but It takes about 1hs to generate it.

Somebody know another library or another method (PDF, JS, Jquery, Canvas) to generate a PDF faster?

Thanks.
Leandro.

Comment: Have you tried their suggested solutions? [mPDF docs](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=266). If you have, could you try lowering the file size of the images? In addition are your images in tables? Are you using negative margins? All these things really slow down the rendering of the document.

Answer (score -1):

If you can run external tools/programs, you can always try to use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

It runs above a headless chrome browser so its results are often even nicer than those of mPDF.